# Bind Dataset (in iframe page) to Repeater (in parent page)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

My default page (default.aspx) contained an iframe and a repeater control.
User will doing data searching in iframe and the result need to be bind to the repeater control in top page.

How I can make it ?

Many thanks !

Comment: Is both the top page and iframe hosted under same website?

Comment: yes, it's under same website.